# A condition for a sequence defined by a recurrence relationship to all be integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

I am interested in a specific sequence $\{a_n \}$ defined by a simple recurrence relationship: $$a_n = \frac {a_{n-1} ^2 +c} {b} $$ where $b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to find all $b,c$ such that there exists some integer $a_1$ such that $\{a_n\} $ are all integers.

I think that this would be a well-known problem, but I have trouble finding it. Even if this is not well-known, I cannot find a way to solve this question.

For example, if $b=3$ and $c=1$, it is fairly trivial that there exists no such $a_1 $. if $b=3$ and $c=2$, we can let $a_1 = 1 $ to make all $\{a_n \}$ be integers. However, I cannot easily work this out even in a single case, such as $b=3, c=17$. Furthermore, how can I find all $(b,c)$ such that there exists some $a_1$ such that $a_n \in \mathbb Z$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

*I posted this on SEMath, but I did not get any answers nor references. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470398/a-condition-for-a-sequence-defined-by-a-recurrence-relationship-to-all-be-intege

Comment: Piggybacking on one of the comments at M.SE, it seems that $b = 2$ and $c = 4k+1$ would be fine, because if $a_1$ is any odd $2m+1$, then $a_2 = 2m^2 + 2m + 2k + 1$ is also odd and thus we get integrality from that point on.

Comment: length  1  a_start 1; 
  length  6  a_start 2; 
  length  12  a_start 23; 
  length  16  a_start 412; 
  length  18  a_start 1075; 
  length  22  a_start 2398;  It hung up while still working on a_start = 3080, so I do not know what happens, just that starting with 3080 does better than the previous ones and reaches length at least 24.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to change notation a little bit to make it easier to describe things, and to put your problem into the general framework of arithmetic dynamics. Let
$$ f(X) = \frac{X^2+c}{b}, $$
and for each $n\ge0$, let $f^n(X)$ denote the $n$'th iterate of $X$.  Then you are asking which $b,c\in\mathbb Z$ have an $a\in\mathbb Z$ such that $f^n(a)\in\mathbb Z$ for all $n\ge0$.

Some observations.

1. The only primes that can occur in the denominator of $f^n(a)$ are primes dividing $b$.
2. It suffices to find, for each prime $p\mid b$, a starting point $\alpha_p\in\mathbb Z$ so that all of the points $f^n(\alpha_p)$ are $p$-adically integral. Once you do that, you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find an $a\in\mathbb Z$ with $a\equiv\alpha_p\pmod{p}$ for all $p\mid b$ and you're done.

I am going to consider the case that $b$ is square-free and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ and that $p\mid b$ is an odd prime. Clearly a necessary condition is that $-c$ is a square mod $p$, since you need $a^2+c$ to be divisible by $p$. This means that your $a$ values must satisfy
$$ a^2 \equiv -c \pmod{p}. $$
So let's assume that you can find some $a_1\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a_1^2\equiv-c\pmod{p}$. (Note that there are only two values for $a_1\bmod p$.) The next step is to let 
$$
  u_1=\frac  { (a_1+py)^2+c } {p}
$$
and try to find $y$ so that $u_1^2\equiv-c\pmod{p}$. Then setting $a_2=a_1+py$ ensures that $f(a_2)$ and $f^2(a_2)$ are both in $\mathbb Z$. If you write out the congruence, you'll find that you can solve for $y$. (This is where I need $p\ne2$.) Repeating the process, we get a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ with the property $$ a_{n+1}\equiv a_n\pmod{p^n}
   \quad\text{and}\quad
  f^i(a_n)\in\mathbb Z\quad\text{for all $0\le i\le n$.}
$$
Hence the $a_n$ converge in $\mathbb Z_p$ to a $p$-adic number $a$ satisfying $f^n(a)\in\mathbb Z_p$ for all $n$. (Further, aside from that initial choice of $\pm a_1$, the sequence $a_n\bmod p^{n+1}$ is uniquely determined.)

Okay, now for the hard part. Is $a=\lim a_n$ in $\mathbb Z$?  If it is, you win, and if not, then there is no $\mathbb Z$ starting point that works.  Possibly $a\in\mathbb Z$ follows from the initial assumption that $b$ and $c$ are in $\mathbb Z$, but I don't see why. And my instinct says that the opposite should be true, and indeed that the value of $a$ will be transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, but again, I don't know how to prove that.

For $p=2$, or if $p\mid\gcd(b,c)$, the analysis will be somewhat different.  And it seems easier to get your condition for $p=2$ because of the extra $2$ in the middle term when you expand $(a_n+2y)^2$.  But at the end of the day, I think it's going to come down to determining whether a certain $p$-adic limit is in $\mathbb Z$.

**Addendum** There are results which say that if $f(X)\in\mathbb Q(X)$ is not a polynomial and also $f^2(X)$ is not a polynomial, then $\{f^n(a):n\ge0\}$ contains only finitely many integers.

Comment: In any case, the two fixed points are $p$-adically integral, and they are in $\mathbb Z$ iff $b^2 - 4c$ is a square (which explains the $b = 3$, $c = 2$ case).

Comment: Just a reminder: there are troubles with CRT argument. Sorry, this part is not indicated in my answer...

Answer (score 3):

$\let\eps\varepsilon$This is not an answer, but just an attempt to summarize flaming (at least inspired by myself, sorry) appeared in the comments to the answer by @Joe Silverman. I would kindly ask Joe's permission to delete those comments, if all of them are correctly reflected here. It is not that convenient to walk through all of them...

On the other hand, I may easily delete this if it disturbes someone.

So, following Joe's approach, we fix an odd $p\mid b$ (assuming $b$ is odd and square-free, and $b\nmid c$) and search for $p$-adic integers $a$ such that for $a_1=a$ the whole sequence consists of $p$-adic integers. Surely, we assume that $-c\equiv \mu^2\pmod{p}$ for some integer $\mu$. Then it is easy to see that if $(a_n)$ is as desired, then $a_n\equiv\pm \mu\pmod p$ for all $n$.

We claim that for every sequence $\eps=(\eps_1,\dots,\eps_n)$ with $\eps_i\in\{-1,1\}$, there exists a unique residue $r_{\eps}$ such that for $a_1\equiv r\pmod{p^n}$ all $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are ($p$-adic) integers with $a_i\equiv\eps_i\mu\pmod p$. The base $n=1$ is clear. For the step, apply the inductive hypothesis to $a_2,\dots,a_{n+1}$; we find that $a_2\equiv r_{\bar\eps}\pmod{p^n}$, where $\bar\eps=(\eps_2,\dots,\eps_{n+1})$. Now, from $a_1^2=ba_2-c$ we obtain two possible residues for $a_1\pmod {p^{n+1}}$ corresponding to $a_1\equiv \pm \mu\pmod p$, as required. The claim is proved.

Thus, for every *infinite* sequence $\eps_1,\eps_2,\dots$ there exists a sequence $r_{\eps_1},r_{\eps_1,\eps_2},\dots$ converging to some $p$-adic integer $R_{\eps_1,\eps_2,\dots}$ (obviously, these residues agree).

Now again comes the hard part. We need to find out whether one of these $p$-adic numbers is actually an integer.

An easy case is when the sequence $\eps_1,\eps_2,\dots$ is periodic. Then, due to the uniqueness, the sequence starting from $R_\eps$ is periodic as well.  This sequence may indeed be constant, e.g. 
$$
  a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}^2+b-1}b, \quad a_1=1.
$$ 
It may also be cyclic with longer period, e.g., 
$$
  a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}^2-(1+b+b^2)}b, \quad a_1=1, \quad a_2=-(b+1).
$$ 
I am almost sure that arbitrarily long periods may appear; but for every fixed choice for $b$ and $c$ they can be found easily: since $\frac{x^2+c}b>x$ for all sufficiently large $x$, it suffices to check only the sequences consistinc of small numbers.

The case when $\eps$ is an aperiodic sequence seems to be, eh, much harder (and, *perhaps*, not approachable by such elementary methods). But still, some heuristics: all the $R_\eps$ form some Cantor set in $p$-adic numbers, and it has zero measure, so it is quite improbable that one of these numbers is integer. Nevertheless, it is not clear why it cannot happen (if it really cannot).

Notice also that in any case, some of the $R_\eps$ are algebraic (two of them satisfies $x^2-bx+c=0$, and some generate longer cycles), while some are transcendent (since there are continuum many of them).

Comment: This looks good. I'll delete my comments, too, since as you say, it's much easier to read a coherent summary.

Comment: Thank you for this good summary! I was working on the same direction until now, and the actual thing I wanted to prove was that $x$ is not an integer if $\epsilon _n $ has infinite period. However, any argument that I could have thought of did not help proving this, even in a single case.

Comment: Is there any kind of a standard way to approach this kind of problems in dynamical systems or etc.? I am still a student studying number theory (by the way, thank you for the great book!), and I don't know anything about this kind of dynamical things.

Comment: Seems that these thanks should come to @JoeSilverman.

Comment: @Houtarou Yes, I agree that the most interesting case would be when your have a wandering (i.e., infinite) orbit. My guess is that except in very rare situations, the $p$-adic solutions will be transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, but I don't know a good approach for attacking such a problem.